# FIRInvalidArgumentException on iPhone 12 & above simulators

Tags: firebase, swiftui

My code was working perfectly fine under iPhone 12 Pro Max simulator, but after i switched to another simulator (iPhone 13), i suddenly get the following error when retrieving firebase data. (Now even if i switched back to any simulator, it is giving me this error)

```
let userID = "XXXXXXX"  //makeup string
db.collection("users").document(userID).getDocument { (snap, err) in. //<--error
            if err != nil{
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            } 
           //do something
}
```

Error as following:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Document path cannot be
> empty.' terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
> CoreSimulator 783.5 - Device: iPhone 12 Pro Max
> (8F16941B-17F5-4810-A5EA-F43F924C9EB3) - Runtime: iOS 15.2 (19C51) -
> DeviceType: iPhone 12 Pro Max

I have tried cleaning up the built folder but it still didn't work.
It was working perfectly before because I was able to create/update/delete data directly with the code above.

May i know what happens here?

**UPDATE:**

I find out the issue appears on iPhone 12 and above simulators. I was working on iPhone 11 Pro.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code in the question so the issue lies in the development environment. Possibly Firebase needs to be updated or CocoaPods or the project. Not much else we can do here without more details.